# How do I get a comparison of Float & Nil to return a valid answer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have something like this:

```
    good_attrs = %w(firm_size priority_level)       

    good_attrs.each do |attr|
      if (score.send(attr) > max.send(attr))
        max.send("#{attr}=", score.send(attr))
      end
    end
```

What happens, though, is that occassionally it may come across a `Max` record that looks like this:

```
#<Max:0x007fe01024b240> {
                           :id => 2,
                      :user_id => 1,
                    :firm_size => 101.0,
               :priority_level => nil,
                   :created_at => Fri, 23 Nov 2012 01:55:53 UTC +00:00,
                   :updated_at => Fri, 23 Nov 2012 01:58:16 UTC +00:00
}
```

i.e. `max.priority_level` = `nil`.

So how do I modify my initial `if statement` to handle `nil` cases on both sides of the evaluation? i.e. if a `score` or `max` attribute is nil. Ideally, I would like it to be treated as `0` and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare `nil` with a `Float`.

In your case you can take advantage of the fact that `nil.to_f == 0.0`:

```
good_attrs = %w(firm_size priority_level)       

good_attrs.each do |attr|
  if score.send(attr).to_f > max.send(attr).to_f
    max.send("#{attr}=", score.send(attr))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the attr_reader for `priority_level` and `firm_size` in `Max`

```
def priority_level
  read_attribute(:priority_level).nil? ? 0 : super
end
```

You can alternatively set default values in an `after_initialize` block

```
after_initialize do
  self.priority_level = 0 if self.priority_level.nil?
end
```

Comment: This won't work, because I have X number of attributes, all of which can have `nil` as a value. So I need to make sure it handles `nil` for all the values.